# Declaring empty functions in typescript

Tags: typescript

I came over a piece of code in a custom component that I have some trouble understanding.

```js
public onTouch: () => void = () => {}
```

The `onTouch` function is set by the private method

```
registerOnTouch(fn: any) {
  this.onTouch = fn;
}
```

I think that the first part `public OnTouch: () = void`  declares a function without parameters that does not return a value. But I struggle to understand the last part `() => ()`.

What does the latter part describe Could it be an overload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part:

```
() => void
```

declares the type of function `onTouch` and the second part:

```
= () => {}
```

declares its default value. That is, in case `onTouch` is not assigned another value, it will be a no-op.